# Does a system with infinite solutions have linearly dependent columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

"If Ax = b has infinitely many solutions, then is the collection of column vectors of
A is linearly dependent?"

I was wondering if this solution works for the following problem

Since Ax = b has infinitely many solutions, it must have at least two distinct solutions X1 and X2. Therefore it is linearly dependent as X1=/=X2. (This is because for a function to be linearly independent, X1=X2=...=Xn=0)

I saw that other solutions used some form of summation to prove it but this is the only one that makes sense to me.

Comment: The solution in the question is totally wrong.

"Therefore it is linearly dependent as X1=/=X2." That is wrong.


"This is because for a function to be linearly independent, X1=X2=...=Xn=0" This does not make sense. A function cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: Voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, if there is more than one solution to $Ax=b$, then the columns of $A$ must be linearly dependent.

Your solution is unclear though. Recall vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ are *linearly dependent* when there are scalars $a_1,...,a_n$, not all zero, such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k v_k=0.$$

---

If $Ax=b$ has distinct solutions $x_1,x_2$, then subtracting equations $Ax_1=b,Ax_2=b$ gives

$$0=A(x_1-x_2)=\sum_i (x_{1,i}-x_{2,i})A_i ,$$

where $A_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$. Since there is some $i$ for which $x_{1,i}- x_{2,i}\neq 0$ , the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: It has not been said that the matrix was a square matrix.

Comment: @R.W.Prado I never assumed $A$ was a square matrix, and was careful in my wording. I am not sure why you thought that.

Comment: The link you posted says that the matrix is Square.

Comment: @R.W.Prado Oh I see. If you notice, my proof is self-contained and doesn't rely on that link. However, the reason I cited that link is because it mentions linearly independent columns and having a trivial null space are equivalent conditions (which is true for any $A$, invertible or not), which relates to this exercise. However, I see how that link may confuse given its ties with invertibility, so I will remove that.

Comment: I see. So by stating that "there is some  for which X1,−X2,≠0", it implies that Ai is 0?

Comment: @BenNet1700 No, that does not imply $A_i=0$. For that matter, we are certainly not trying to show $A_i=0$.

Comment: @BenNet1700 What we did is we found a zero-valued linear combo of columns of $A$, where the scalars used in the linear combo (i.e. $x_{1,i}-x_{2,i}$) are not all zero. Hopefully, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax=b$ and $A$ is invertible then multiplying by $A^{-1}$ we get $$x=A^{-1}b$$ which is а unique solution. So for such an equation to have infinite solutions it has to have a degenerate $A$ matrix (otherwise we get the unique solution above), which is equivalent to $A$ having linearly dependent columns.

Comment: It has not been said that $A$ was a square matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ have linearly independent columns, the application $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $T(x)=Ax,$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, is injective. This means that, whenever a solution of the system $T(x)=b$ exists, the solution is unique. This is exactly the contrapositive of your result. Hence your result is true, and, whenever the system have more than one solution, the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.

---

**Result**: If $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times m}$ have linearly independent columns, the application $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $T(x)=Ax,$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, is injective.

**Proof**:
Note that, for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, if $T(x)=T(y)$, we have $T(x-y)=0$. Since the columns of $A$, say $a_1, \cdots, a_m$, are linearly independent and $\sum^{m}_{i=1}(x_i-y_i)a_i=T(x-y)=0$, being the $i-$th coordinate of $z$ denoted by $z_i$, we have $x_i-y_i=0,$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m.$ Thus, $x=y.$